# In VBA, how does one make a table from a recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a recordset that I want to export into Excel 2000 format (acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9). I believe I need to drop it into a table first then execute a DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet (keeps it easy and it works). The user sets just a few parameters in the form, thus the **Me.** syntax you will see.

Here's the working code so far:

```
Select Case Me.Controls("frame_ChooseReport").Value
    Case 1
        sExecuteQuery = "qry_PDSR w/ Destruct Dates"
        bHasProgramCode = True
        sFileName = "Project_Doc_Submittal_Request_better"
    Case 2
        sExecuteQuery = "qry_PDSR w/Destruct Dates BE"
        bHasProgramCode = False  'This is the only query here that doesn't have a Program Code parameter
        sFileName = "Project_Doc_Submittal_Request_better_BE"
    Case 3
        sExecuteQuery = "qry_Project Documentation Submittal Request w/ Destruct Dates"
        bHasProgramCode = True
        sFileName = "Project_Doc_Submittal_Request_ENH"
    Case 4
        sExecuteQuery = "qry_Project_Doc_Submittal_Request_w_Destruct_Dates_HES_Installer"
        bHasProgramCode = True
        sFileName = "Project_Doc_Submittal_Request_Installer"
    Case Else
        Stop  'Error!  This should never be reached!
End Select
'Execute query & save output to Excel
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(sExecuteQuery)  'Open the query

'Assign values to the query using the parameters option
If bHasProgramCode = True Then
    qdf.Parameters(0) = Me.lbl_ProgramCodes.Section
    qdf.Parameters(1) = Me.txt_StartDate
    qdf.Parameters(2) = Me.txt_EndDate
Else
    qdf.Parameters(0) = Me.txt_StartDate
    qdf.Parameters(1) = Me.txt_EndDate
End If

sFullPath = Me.lbl_SaveTo.Caption & "\" & sFileName
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset  'Convert the querydef to a recordset and run it
If rst.BOF = True And rst.EOF = True Then
    MsgBox "No records were found.", vbExclamation, "Empty recordset"
    Exit Sub
End If
'Dump recordset into a table, export it to Excel, then delete it.

'Here is where the recordset needs to become a table.

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "qry_PDSR w/ Destruct Dates", sFullPath, True  'Export table to an Excel format

'Clean up!
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, gTEMP_TBL  'Done with the temporary table so delete it
rst.Close
qdf.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
```

Help/suggestions? Thank you.

Access 2010 in Windows 7

**---------- FOLLOW UP ----------**

Here's the query I added that will use the references of the opened form per Remou's suggestion:

```
SELECT dbo_PROJECT.PROJECTID, dbo_PROJECT.TITLE, dbo_PROJECT.PROGRAMCODE, dbo_PROJECT.PROJECTTYPE, dbo_PROJECT.REFERENCE, dbo_PROJECT.STATUS, dbo_PROJECT.PMC, dbo_TRANSACTION_SUM.STATUS, dbo_TRANSACTION_SUM.IMPORTEDDT, dbo_TRANSACTION_SUM.CHECKDT, dbo_PROJECT.NOTES, dbo_TRANSACTION_SUM.TRANSACTIONID, dbo_TRANSACTION_SUM.GL_ACCT, dbo_PROJECT_SUM.PAID_INCENT_TOTAL, dbo_TRANSACTION_SUM.AMOUNT
FROM ((dbo_INCENTIVE RIGHT JOIN dbo_PROJECT ON dbo_INCENTIVE.PROJECTID = dbo_PROJECT.PROJECTID) LEFT JOIN dbo_TRANSACTION_SUM ON dbo_INCENTIVE.INCENTIVEID = dbo_TRANSACTION_SUM.INCENTIVEID) LEFT JOIN dbo_PROJECT_SUM ON dbo_PROJECT.PROJECTID = dbo_PROJECT_SUM.PROJECTID
WHERE (((dbo_PROJECT.PROGRAMCODE) In ([Forms]![Submittal_Request_Report]![txt_ListProgramCodeSelections])) AND ((dbo_TRANSACTION_SUM.CHECKDT) Between [Forms]![Submittal_Request_Report]![txt_StartDate] And [Forms]![Submittal_Request_Report]![txt_EndDate]));
```

Here's the routine that is in the On_Exit event of the listbox:

```
Private Sub list_ProgramCodes_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
'Get selection from Program Code listbox and store it in a hidden textbox for the query.
Dim x As Long, sValue As String, ctlSource As Control

sValue = ""
Set ctlSource = Me!list_ProgramCodes
For x = 0 To ctlSource.ListCount - 1
    If ctlSource.Selected(x) Then
        sValue = sValue & ctlSource.Column(0, x) & ","
    End If
Next
Me.txt_ListProgramCodeSelections.Value = Left(sValue, Len(sValue) - 1)  'Drop the last comma
Set ctlSource = Nothing
End Sub
```

Works great!  The SQL line **In ([Forms]![Submittal_Request_Report]![txt_ListProgramCodeSelections])** pulls the list of items in the hidden textbox (using a label didn't work) that was populated with the selection from the listbox on the form.

This is now the code for exporting the query:

```
Private Sub btn_RunReport_Click()
Dim sExecuteQuery As String, sFullPath As String, sFileName As String

On Error GoTo Err_btn_RunReport_Click
If Left(Me.lbl_SaveTo.Caption, 4) = "save" Then
    MsgBox "Please select a folder to save the results to.", vbInformation, "No folder selected"
    Exit Sub
End If

Select Case Me.Controls("frame_ChooseReport").Value
    Case 1
        sExecuteQuery = "qry_PDSR_Destruct_Dates_form"
        sFileName = "Project_Doc_Submittal_Request.xls"
    Case 2
        sExecuteQuery = "qry_Project_Doc_Submittal Request w/ Destruct Dates_form"
        sFileName = "Project_Doc_Submittal_Request_ENH.xls"
    Case 3
        sExecuteQuery = "qry_PDSR_w_Destruct_Dates_HES_Installer_form"
        sFileName = "Project_Doc_Submittal_Request_Installer.xls"
    Case Else
        Stop  'Error!  This should never be reached!
End Select
sFullPath = Me.lbl_SaveTo.Caption & "\" & sFileName
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, sExecuteQuery, sFullPath, True  'Export table to an Excel format

Exit_btn_RunReport_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_btn_RunReport_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_btn_RunReport_Click

End Sub
```

Thanks Remou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you just set the sql of a query to a suitable string and then export the query:

```
sSQL="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field=" & me.MyText
If IsNull(DLookup("name", "msysobjects", "name='query1'")) Then
    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "Query1", sSQL
Else
    CurrentDB.QueryDefs("Query1").SQL = sSQL
End If     

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Query1", sFullPath
```

You can create a query that references an open form:

```
SELECT Test.ID, Test.Data
FROM Test
WHERE Test.AField=[forms]![test]![pickone]
```

Comment: Remou, I've amended my code to include how the query to run is determined.

Comment: You should avoid temporary tables as much as possible, and in this case it is possible. It should not be much work to create a set of queries that reference a form for parameters rather than filling in the parameters from form controls in code.

Comment: I've read about referencing parameters from forms (like you suggest) so I could do that.  The reason for my original request is that the db I inherited already has the queries made for reports, so by leaving them alone the query that feeds the report can be used by the report itself (prompting the user when necessary) or a 'prettier' method of using the form (this code).

Comment: Creating temporary tables leads to bloat. Do you want that? Furthermore, the most efficient way of creating a table is going to involve a query, so why not just export the query?

Comment: Ah, bloat!  Thanks for the explanation.  I'll make a set of queries for the form object per your suggestion.  As for exporting the query, Access ends up saving it in Excel in Outline formatting, something which the end users cannot stand, while using the TransferSpreadsheet command just dumps the raw table (what they want...seriously!).  I do *know* Excel VBA so, yeah, I could manipulate the output from Access but I have bigger fish to fry.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: "Excel in Outline formatting" - it shouldn't. I don't get that problem when exporting queries with DoCmd.transferSpreadsheet.

Comment: You are correct.  Other methods dump the table to Excel in outline format but not TransferSpreadsheet (which is what I'll use).  I apologize for not being more clear.  I'm learning!